# Andengine ON_MOVE Event Always Works On New Phones

Tags: android, andengine, touch-event

Hi i use andengine in my game. It had worked fine until new phones such as s4, htc one appears. When touch events occur, if the touch event is down then up(no move) it always go into on_move event at these new phones. But at older phones, when up event occur, on_move event never works. What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. You can not assume how many move events fired between the down and up event. Even if you think your finger is pressing down at the same place, the touch point coordinate still change...

Comment: There is no mistake in any of the things. These newer devices have higher processor compare to older one. So it easily detect movement of finger between touch down and up. As a result you have to code in such way that this thing does not put any barrier.